# Brackets shell not running node commands

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have just installed the Brackets Shell extension (Mac OSX 10.9) and can run normal shell commands (ls, pwd), but not node commands (bower install, npm install). I get 'command not found'. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run `echo $PATH`, what do you see? Does it differ from the results if you run the same thing in regular Mac OS Terminal?

Comment: Yes it is different:
in brackets shell: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin 
in normal shell: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/gsutil

Comment: The only way I've been able to fix this is by symlinking to `/usr/bin/` by doing something like this:

`cd /usr/bin/`
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm npm`
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bower bower`

Answer (score 0):

Currently the brackets shell extension has a bug in that it is not reading your profile path environment.  This is why you are receiving "command not found" in the console.

I'll be releasing an update to the shell extension this coming weekend (10/4/2014) which should resolve your issues.

Comment: This post provides no answer

Comment: Are you the author of the Shell Extension? If so does the extension have version number? So others can later see if the problem has been selved for them.

Comment: @codingFriend1, the version which will address the issue explained here will be 0.0.5.

Comment: It's now 11/3/2014 and I see that the latest release of the extension is still 0.0.4 and it does not address this issue. Any update?

Comment: The latest version out there now is v0.0.12.  These issues I believe have been resolved. You can now also specify the shell in which you wish to you by setting the hdy.brackets-shell.shell preference in the brackets preferences.

Comment: @john.hidey Still not reading my .profile, set both sh and bash still not reading!